# Credit card Formatting function in Yii

Tags: php, yii, credit-card, number-formatting

I want to format the credit cards like below when i display it,

Eg:

```
1234 4567 9874 1222
```

as

```
1xxx xxxx xxx 1222
```

Is there any formatting function like this in Yii ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you could also use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) :

```
$card='1234 4567 9874 1222';
$xcard = preg_replace('/^([0-9])([- 0-9]+)([0-9]{4})$/', '${1}xxx xxxx xxxx ${3}', $card);
```

This regex will also take care of hyphens.

There is no in-built function in Yii.

Answer (score 2):

No - but there's nothing wrong with using straight PHP.

If you always want the 1st and the last 4 chars you can do something like this:

```
$last4 = substr($cardNum, -4);
$first = substr($cardNum, 0, 1);

$output = $first.'xxx xxxx xxxx '.$last4;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, nothing Yii specific
You could do it using str_split (untested):

```
$string = "1234 4567 1234 456";
$character_array = str_split($string);
for ($i = 1; $i < count($character_array) - 4; $i++) {
    if ($character_array[$i] != " "){
        $character_array[$i] = "x";
    }
}
echo implode($character_array);
```

- So we are creating an array of characters from the string called
  $character_array.
- We are then looping thru the characters (starting from position 1,
  not 0, so the first character is visible).
- We loop until the number of entries in the array minus 4 (so the last
  4 characters are not replaced) We replace each character in the loop 
  with an 'x' (if it's not equal to a space)
- We the implode the array back into a string